# Faraday's law in cases of quasistatic approximation

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, magnetic-fields, electric-circuits

In a text I am using (Griffiths) it states "The regime in which magnetostatic rules can be used to calculate the magnetic field on the right hand side of Faraday's law, is called **quasistatic**." It then states Farady's law as $$\oint \vec{E} \cdot d \vec{l} = - \int \frac{d}{dt}\vec{B} \cdot d \vec{a} =  -  \frac{d}{dt}\int\vec{B} \cdot d \vec{a} .$$ Is the quasistatic approximation somehow use to justify taking the derivative out of the integral, if so how?

Also, what are the general requirements (or related Theorem) necessary for the a derivative of a function of two variables to be taken out of the integral, for example: $$\int \frac{d}{dt}\vec{B} \cdot d \vec{a} = \frac{d}{dt} \int \vec{B} \cdot d \vec{a}$$ where $\vec{B}$ is a function of area and time and $d \vec{a}$ is the differential of area only. So I guess generally when is is possible to have $$\int g(f(x,t))dx = g(\int f(x,t) dx)$$ where $g$ is a function of $t$ only.

Thanks.

Comment: IIRC, one can take the time derivative outside of the surface integral if the path $\Sigma$ that bounds the surface does not change with time.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Oh okay so in the case of using Farady's law, that basically means always, since the Amperian loop you choose would not be time dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theorem that you can change the order of differentiation and integration in equation $$\int \frac{∂}{dt}\vec{B} \cdot d \vec{a} = \frac{d}{dt} \int \vec{B} \cdot d \vec{a}$$ is called [Leibniz's integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign). It requires that the integrand and its partial time derivative are continuous functions in space and time, that the integration surface including boundary path are constant in time, and that $div{\vec B}=0$ holds (no magnetic charge density exists). If the integration surface and boundary path are moving, Leibniz's rule is mathematically extended by a line integral giving the magnetic Lorentz force term.